# Set status bar color to transparent makes other views in the activity transparent

Tags: android

I created this layout file `@+id/activity_play_panel` for an activity.

```
<LinearLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_play_panel"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.michael.musicplayer.PlayPanel">

<View
    android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="#00FFFF"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"/>
```

I then added the following java code to make the **black bar UNDERNEATH the status bar** in `@+id/activity_play_panel` tranparent.

```
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable( Color.TRANSPARENT );
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable( colorDrawable );
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

However, after I added the code to make the status bar transparent, the second view in `@+id/activity_play_panel` also turned transparent.

If I reverse the order of the views, then I can see the second view, but not the first view e.g.

```
<!-- Not transparent-->

<View
    android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="#00FFFF"/>

<!-- Transparent-->

<View
    android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"/>
```

Or on reversal

```
<!-- Not transparent-->

<View
    android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"/>

<!-- Transparent-->

<View
    android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="#00FFFF"/>
```

Comment: Just as a remark, I've noticed you didn't specify the orientation which is horizontal by default

Answer (score 0):

The default orientation for a linear layout is horizontal.

I simply had to set the parent linear layout to orientation vertical.

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it ^^ 
its because you did match_parent in rectangle_at_the_bottom height value ! 
change it to this :

```
<View
android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_bottom"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="10dp"
android:background="#000000"/>
```